# More highlighted items in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, highlight

I have a `ListBox`, in which data are put. Simple strings, nothing extreme. But, the user chooses what the data will be and he can and two different (!!!) objects, which have the same name.

Example: It is used with connection with pictures. Every picture has a name. And the user selects pictures and adds them to the listbox. But, if he chooses two pictures with the same name, this happens what selecting items in the listbox:

[image]

What shall I do, in order to avoid this? I want only one highlighted and selected item.
The listbox is set on a single selection, and on the selection event, it says that only one item is selected. So it concerns only the highlight.
(using WPF, C#)

Comment: Could you show us you listbox declaration?

Comment: what about just making the names different (adding `(1)`, `(2)`, ...)?

Comment: listbox declaration:             <ListBox x:Name="listBoxLekceVyberanePolozky" Margin="9.999,10,23.508,15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="22" SelectionChanged="listBoxLekceVyberanePolozky_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

Comment: unfortunately that would cause a confusion on the side of the user

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this you'll have to use a wrapper around your strings; your **Picture** objects seems a good start.

Here is a sample that illustrates the two approaches:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures1}" />
        <ListBox x:Name="list2" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures2}" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Content="+" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Picture
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Pictures1 { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures2 { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Pictures1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Pictures2 = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Pictures1.Add(Text);
            Pictures2.Add(new Picture { Name = Text });

            list1.SelectedItem = Pictures1[0];
            list2.SelectedItem = Pictures2[0];
        }
    }
}
```

You can also bind more info like the extension, size, or any property that can help the user.

Hope this helps...